# if else wont work as it should JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, button, logic

I am trying to make the if statement work but I dont know how's the right way to express it.

```
Button button_2 = new Button("Delete");
button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

Here I get the selection of the row and column which I intend to manipulate later.

```
        int column =0;
        int row = table_1.getSelectedRow(); 
        String id= table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();

                if (id==null) { // won't work as it should ? 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a row to delete!");


                  }else {


                        try{ 
                            String query3 = "DELETE FROM hostel_dtrm  WHERE id=?";
                            PreparedStatement pst= conn1.prepareStatement(query3);

                                pst.setString(1, id);
                                pst.executeUpdate();


                     // Printing the results after Row Deletion
                    String query2= "SELECT * FROM hostel_dtrm";
                    PreparedStatement psts= conn1.prepareStatement(query2);
                    ResultSet rs=psts.executeQuery();

                    table_1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                    // Closing stuff
                      pst.close();
                      rs.close();   

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Row Deleted");

                   }catch(Exception err){
                        System.err.println(err);    
                        }

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: just the fact that it's a result of a toString means it can't be null. what "doesn't work as it should" ?

Comment: It actually works exactly as it should. Use debugger tools, and you'll see that.

Comment: please explain me how to express if row  not selected

Comment: It works as it *should* (as you written), but not exactly as you *want*. To make it work like you want we need to know how you would like it to work. Use [edit] option and clarify your question.

Comment: Also please fix indentation of your code. Any decent editor should have tool which can do it for you. Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're selecting a row from a JTable. Note that the `getSelectedRow()` method returns `-1` if no row is selected ([documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow())).

So, you should check if `row` is `-1` before getting the value at that row/column:

```
...
int column = 0;
int row = table_1.getSelectedRow();
if (row == -1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a row to delete!");
} else {
    String id = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();
    ...
}
```